# OpenCV Center Based Histogram

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to make a center based histogram which means the values of an RGB image that are in the middle is more important. I wrote the code below but it is very slow according to OpenCV's own histogram function. Is there any way to make this fast?

```
void calc_histogram(cv::Mat& image, cv::Mat& histogram)
{
int bit = 8;
int max_value = pow(2, bit);

int n_blue_bin = 8;
int n_green_bin = 8;
int n_red_bin = 8;

int blue_width = max_value / n_blue_bin;
int green_width = max_value / n_green_bin;
int red_width = max_value / n_red_bin;

int mySizes[3]={n_blue_bin, n_green_bin, n_red_bin};
histogram = Mat::zeros(3,mySizes,CV_32F);

int blue, green, red;
int blue_bin, green_bin, red_bin;

float k, length;
float max_length = sqrt((image.rows/2)*(image.rows/2) + (image.cols/2)*(image.cols/2));

for(int i = 0 ; i < image.rows ; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0 ; j < image.cols ; j++)
    {
        length = sqrt(abs(image.rows/2 - i)*abs(image.rows/2 - i) + abs(image.cols/2 - j)*abs(image.cols/2 - j)) / max_length;
        k = sqrt(1-length);

        Vec3b intensity = image.at<Vec3b>(i, j);
        blue = intensity.val[0];
        green = intensity.val[1];
        red = intensity.val[2];

        blue_bin = blue / blue_width;
        green_bin = green / green_width;
        red_bin = red / red_width;
        histogram.at<float>(blue_bin, green_bin, red_bin) += k;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you profiled your code?  That's usually a good start.  I suspect that the two calls to `sqrt()` in your inner loop are likely to be prime suspects when you do...

Comment: @TobySpeight They maybe are, but I think they are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look right to me as a histogram function: Should your result really be an 8x8x8 matrix? Usually a histogram is 3xNumBins. To add, do histogram[0][red]+=k; histogram[1][green]+=k; histogram[2][blue]+=k; Usually k=1, but in your case it's a weight. Maybe I am reading opencv wrong though.

Also you are doing a lot of superfluous work: Why abs before squaring? Never divide when you can multiply by reciprocal. Iterate y then x. Don't use at, but get a pointer instead.

Comment: Yes I get a 8x8x8 matrix as I want, there is no problem about the values. Yes I am doing something different from usual histogram. And you are right about abs(). I will fix it. But I did not get the reciprocal and at part.

Comment: @JennySimon Reciprocal: It is much faster to multiply by 1/x than dividing by x. Precompute those. At: Use .ptr(row) instead of at. Flip your loop to go columns in the inner loop. Then do ptr once per row and index myptr[col]. Also re-think your use of sqrt. Can't you just use the square length instead of two roots?